# Animate effect when div detected through viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just wondering if you all could help me out.

I am creating a webpage that uses animate effects (slideInLeft) but I want this to only be activated once the div is detectable through the viewport.

I have tried plugins, to no success, but I feel there should be an easier solution than multiple plugins.

I have created a codepen below:

https://codepen.io/jmac1988/pen/aWPRxo

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('#topsub').each(function() {
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
    var imageHeight = $(this).height();
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (imagePos < topOfWindow + imageHeight && imagePos + imageHeight >
      topOfWindow) {
      $(this).addClass(".slideRight");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass(".slideRight");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.top {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: rgb(211, 243, 243);
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 150px;
}

#topsub {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 243, 182);
  font-family: 'Sofia Pro';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#toptitle {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 243, 182);
  font-family: 'Sofia Pro Semi';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 4em;
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideInLeft {
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pt-page pt-page-1">
  <div class="top">
    <p id="top1"><span id="topsub" class="animated slideInLeft">THE 
    PRACTICE OF EVERYDAY LIFE</span><br>
      <span id="toptitle" class="animated slideInLeft">Michel de Certeau</span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by div detect please clear.

Answer (score 0):

try using "detect.js" javascript library. That can detect type of device by the viewport. By using this you can handle the animation.
Get the library from the below link
https://github.com/darcyclarke/Detect.js/tree/master